# Meteor.js Smart Package: Npm.require cannot find module

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, meteorite

I'm getting an error in a package I've created called shippo. I'm using Meteor version 1.0.3.2

When calling it on the server the error is

```
Error: Cannot find module 'shippo'
```

This is my code requiring it in packages/shippo/shippo.js

```
Shippo = Npm.require("shippo")('<USERNAME>', '<PASSWORD>');
```

This is in packages/shippo/package.js

```
Npm.depends({
  "shippo": "1.0.2"
});
```

When I run

```
npm view shippo
```

it returns

```
{ name: 'shippo',
  description: 'Shippo API wrapper',
  'dist-tags': { latest: '1.0.2' },
  versions: [ '0.0.1', '1.0.0', '1.0.2' ],
...
```

Comment: Where is this code executing `Shippo = Npm.require("shippo")('<USERNAME>', '<PASSWORD>');` ? In the server code or in the package code ?

Comment: this is being executed in the root directory. packages/shippo/shippo.js